# Get object ID inside array Mongodb Nodejs REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have been created a rest api with nodejs and mongodb atlas.

I have an array of objects each object has an id and I want to get those object by id

[image: data structure]

```
exports.GetUserInfo = (req , res  , next)=>{
Client.find({ReadingHistory: 
mongoose.Schema.ObjectId("5e557c8f0fda580b28866b9f")})
.select()
.exec()
.then(doc=>{        
    if (doc) {
        console.log('from the database',doc);
    } else {
        console.log('invalid ID')
    }

        if (doc) {
            res.status(200).json({
                ReadingHistory: doc,

            });  
        } else {
            res.status(404).json({message: 'Sorry... no data'})
        }

  })
     .catch(err =>{ 
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({error: err})
     });
}


}
```

Comment: Wht do you want to do ? Where do you want to store the ids ? Buzzwords: `forEach` `map` `for` `find` Im not sure what you try to archive.

Comment: @Marc I want to get those history to view it to the user in the mobile application

Answer (score 0):

The ObjectId from MongoDB can't be compared by === or !==, we have to use `ObjectId.prototype.equals`. So you can write the following code:

```js
function find(id) {
  return resultArray.find(obj => obj._id.equals(id));
}
```

And the complete pseudo code could be:

```js
exports.GetUserInfo = (req , res , next) => {
  const conditions = {id: req.params.clientId};
  const result = Client.find(conditions); // suppose Client.find() returns the query result from mongodb.
  return result.ReadingHistory.find(Obj => obj._id.equals(conditions));
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but it give me error message that ReadingHistory is not defined

Comment: `exports.GetUserInfo = (req , res  , next)=>{
    var conditions = {id: req.params.clientId};
     Client.find(conditions) ; {
        return ReadingHistory.find(Obj => obj._id.equals(conditions));
    };

}`

Comment: `ReadingHistory` should be the resulting array which has been returned by mongodb client, as your picture above showed.

Comment: and after **find(conditions)** gives Unexpected token {

Comment: I must add **;**

Comment: `exports.GetUserInfo = (req , res , next)=>{ var conditions = {id: req.params.clientId}; Client.find(conditions){ return [ReadingHistory].find(Obj => obj._id.equals(conditions)); }; }` I got the same error

Comment: `{
    "error": {
        "message": "Cannot read property 'find' of undefined"
    }
} I got this new error message when I run theabove code`

Comment: In the picture from your original post, what is the code to print the array? Show me this code snippet.

Comment: Client.update(conditions , {$push: {
        Readinghistory : {
            heart_beat: req.body.heart_beat,
            blood_oxygen: req.body.blood_oxygen,
            temprature:req.body.temprature,
            blood_pressure:req.body.blood_pressure
          }
     }
})

Comment: if you please advise me if you have a best way to push if something wrong

Comment: So, the array is in the mongodb collection. Your question is how to query one item by a given id from mongodb. Right?

Comment: Then you should use mongodb api [db.collection.findOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/).